# Why is the struct memory size inconsistent with my expectations?

Tags: go

I initialized a struct and calculated the memory, which is inconsistent with my expectations.

the code is:

```
type Man struct {
Name     string
Money    int
Age      int32
}

func main() {

m := Man{Name:"james", Money:1000000, Age:30}

fmt.Println("man size:", unsafe.Sizeof(m))
fmt.Println("name size:", unsafe.Sizeof(m.Name))
fmt.Println("money size:", unsafe.Sizeof(m.Money))
fmt.Println("age size:", unsafe.Sizeof(m.Age))
}
```

the result is:

```
man size: 32
name size: 16
money size: 8
age size: 4
```

The result of my expected size of 'man' is 16 + 8 + 4=28,but fact is 32

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: It is padding to align struct items to 8-byte boundaries to optimize access. It is usually faster to access a single unit of memory aligned properly, based on the memory bus size. For 64-bits, that's 8 bytes, so compiler chose to align all fields to be accessed as 8-byte units.

Comment: My operating system is 64 bit, if so<br>
···
type A1 struct { <br>
   a bool //1byte   assign 8byte  <br>
   b uint32 //4byte <br>
   c bool //1byte <br>
   d uint32 //4byte remain 2byte, not enough 4byte,again assign 8byte<br>
   e uint8 //1byte<br>
   f uint32 //4byte remain 3byte, not enough 4byte,again assign 8byte<br>
   g uint8 //1byte<br>
}<br>
···
size of A1 Should is: 8+8+8=24,but fact is:28<br>

Is there something wrong with my understanding? <br>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Size and alignment guarantees](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees):

> For the numeric types, the following sizes are guaranteed:

```
type                                 size in bytes

byte, uint8, int8                     1
uint16, int16                         2
uint32, int32, float32                4
uint64, int64, float64, complex64     8
complex128                           16
```

> The following minimal alignment properties are guaranteed:
>   1. For a variable x of any type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is at least 1.
>   2. For a variable x of struct type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the largest of all the values unsafe.Alignof(x.f) for each field f of x, but at least 1.
>   3. For a variable x of array type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the same as the alignment of a variable of the array's element type.
>   A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

Then, read these:
[Memory Layouts](https://go101.org/article/memory-layout.html)
[Padding is hard - Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard)

Explanation on 64 bit machine:

Your type is struct and its size depends on how underlying types were defined. Two structs with same fields but different order may have different sizes. Size of struct is counted accordingly with padding and alignment rules.

[image: Struct alignment]

Note: each colored box is one byte.
Try it [here](http://golang-sizeof.tips/?t=Ly8gU2FtcGxlIGNvZGUKc3RydWN0IHsKICAgIE5hbWUgICAgIHN0cmluZwogICAgTW9uZXkgICAgaW50CiAgICBBZ2UgICAgICBpbnQzMgp9Cg==), and edit the struct then press the `Ask` button on top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

You may find [this sizeof explainer](http://golang-sizeof.tips/) helpful; I certainly have.

For the [example in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810906/why-is-the-struct-memory-size-inconsistent-with-my-expectations#comment103902120_58810906), with fields of type `bool`, `uint32`, `bool`, `uint32`, `uint8`, `uint32`, and `uint8`, go uses 4-byte alignment, because none of the individual types is larger than that. Every 1-byte field in that example ends up using four bytes, because each of them is only next to 4-byte types. Each field ends up using four bytes, for a total of 28. If you rearrange the fields so that all four 1-byte fields are at the beginning or the end, they can all be packed into a single 4-byte window, so the whole struct only takes 16 bytes.

For the example in your original post, go uses 8-byte alignment, because one of the struct fields requires at least eight bytes, so the fields use 16, 8, and 8 bytes respectively for a total of 32. In this case there's no benefit to rearranging the fields, because only one of them is smaller than the alignment.